# How to convert a Guid when copying data from a database into private members - C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to copy data from my database into private data members (so that it ultimately may be displayed in an ASP Listbox). I have easily achieved this with strings and integers, e.g.:

```
Forename = Convert.ToString(DB.DataTable.Rows[0]["Forename"]);
PhoneNumber = Convert.ToInt32(DB.DataTable.Rows[0]["PhoneNumber"]);
```

The data for forename and phone number can consequently be passed and used in a listbox. When trying to achieve the same for the primary key, a uniqueidentifier/GUID, the data doesn't pass (it shows up as empty/null/lots of 0s in place of the actual value). I've tried this:

```
UserID = new Guid(Convert.ToString(DB.DataTable.Rows[0]["UserID"]));
```

AND

```
UserID = new Guid(DB.DataTable.Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString());
```

I've also tried this, which results in the error 'cannot convert from object to byte[]':

```
UserID = new Guid(DB.DataTable.Rows[0]["UserID"]);
```

I'm clueless on how to proceed. Any help's appreciated. To reiterate: The first two solutions I've tried don't result in errors, but the data doesn't pass (it shows up as 0s/empty in a listbox).

Any help's appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just use the GUID as a string? Most of the C# templates (for example the Asp.Net with Identity) do this.

Comment: What is the data type of `UserID` in the **database**?

Comment: Does `Convert.ToString(DB.DataTable.Rows[0]["UserID"])` look like the correct representation of a GUID?

Comment: Can you post an example showing the contents of `Rows[n]["UserID"]`? Sounds like it might not be the correct format.

Answer (score -3):

Make your `UserID` member a `string`, and just use `Convert.ToString(DB.DataTable.Rows[0]["UserID"])`

Comment: Would love to see an explanation of the down-votes. Microsoft's Asp.Net Core templates use a `string` Id property, which is a GUID.

Comment: I down voted because it was not the answer to the question.  Doesn’t matter what is in core temples... He wanted a GUID, not a string.

Comment: Sorry, I assume when a new user comes on that they might need help finding a better way. I suppose I can keep that in the comments next time. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ShaneRay I thought this was interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, it actually says providing a viable alternative is fine under "Answer the Question".